# Unexpected error while deploying Nextjs app to firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I am trying to deploy  Nextjs app to firebase hosting , I have followed the instructions  from [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/frameworks/nextjs)
, then I run the following command :

**firebase deploy --only hosting**

And I got this error

[image]

**Environment**

System : macOS ventura 13.3.1

NPM  : 9.5.1

Node : 18.16.0

Firebase-cli : 11.16.0

**Firebase.json**

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "source": "hosting",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "latest",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^17.0.43",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.12",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.5",
    "typescript": "^4.7.3"
  }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by upgrading firebase-cli to version 11.29.1